# How to add one to a value in the page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, django, dom

I have two icons for increasing or decreasing a value in the `span` element.

I have the following code HTML:

```
<td>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>
    <span>{{ item.qty }}</span>
    <a class="triangle_right" href="{% url 'add-to-bag' item.item.upc %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i></a>
</td>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".triangle_right").on("click", function(){

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,

        success: function(data){
            $("#small-bag").html(data);
            $(this).prev().html('0');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

As you can see I am trying to update two elements after a user clicks an icon. The first element with id `#small-bag` gets updated, but the second element doesn't. I am trying to update the `span` element value, in fact, I want to add `1` to the currently displayed value. How can I do that? Also, I am putting my icon inside `a` tags so that it can be clicked to send a request, can I not use the `a` tag and still call the url with just the `i` tag?

P.S. I am using `0` as a placeholder right now. But I want to actually add one to the currently displayed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in the `$.ajax` `success` handler is not the `.triangle-right` element which was clicked on; you need to save that reference in a variable. Try this:

```
$(".triangle_right").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $triangle = $(this);
    var url = $triangle.attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            $("#small-bag").html(data);
            $triangle.prev().html('0');
        }
    });
});
```

To add one to the current value of the element you can do this - assuming it will *always* contain a numeric value only:

```
$triangle.prev().text(function(i, t) {
    return parseInt(t, 10) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Will your second code replace the second line of the success block?

Comment: Hey thanks. This worked fine. I have two more questions. What advantage does `e.preventDefault()` have over `return false;`? And I can use the `url` variable without the $ sign but the `triangle` variable doesn't work without the dollar sign, why is that?

Comment: `return false` stops both the default event behaviour and event propagation, `preventDefault()` only stops the event behaviour. It's better practice to only cancel what you need. The `$` prefix on the variable name is just a naming convention (to show the var contains a jQuery object), it has no other logic associated. I would check for errors in the console if removing the `$` causes issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can't vote accepted within 10 mins of original post. Cheers! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.